# Font is not available to the JVM with Jasper Reports in Docker Container

Tags: java, docker, fonts, jasper-reports

I'm trying to generate a report with DynamicJasper in Docker container?
If I get the followfing error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException:  
                                 Font 'Arial' is not available to the JVM.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I used a Dockerfile like the one below and the problem was solved.
I tried searching for the font in the filesystem in container, with:

```
ls /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/
```

I can see the fonts loaded the folder.

```
FROM openjdk:8u141-jre
COPY /build/libs/my-app*.jar /my-app.jar
EXPOSE 9500

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
RUN echo "deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse  deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse  deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/multiverse.list
RUN echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true |  debconf-set-selections
RUN ["apt-get", "-y", "install", "ttf-mscorefonts-installer"]
RUN dpkg-reconfigure  ttf-mscorefonts-installer
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https apt-utils
RUN apt-get install  --reinstall -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer
CMD java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal $JAVA_OPTS -jar /my-app.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, the JVM itself does not hold any font. That's why you have to install them by yourself. Your solution seems already good. For Debian-based Docker images I do the following:

```
#Add non-free repositories to get MS fonts

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common
RUN apt-add-repository contrib
RUN apt-get update

# If you want to use Microsoft fonts in reports, you must install the fonts
# Andale Mono, Arial Black, Arial, Comic Sans MS, Courier New, Georgia, Impact,
# Times New Roman, Trebuchet, Verdana,Webdings)
RUN echo "ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true" | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends fontconfig ttf-mscorefonts-installer
ADD localfonts.conf /etc/fonts/local.conf
RUN fc-cache -f -v


# If you want to use special characters, such as chinese ideograms, you must install a 
font that support them
# For example:
RUN apt install -y fonts-wqy-zenhei
```

The localfonts.conf file is an optimized for tweaking some anti-aliasing rules for the 'msttcorefonts' collection. Yo can find it here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts#Manual_Font_Smoothing
Unfortunatly the file length is too file to share it on SO, but it's resonable to suppose that the link I posted will be kept on Ubuntu wiki.

Comment: When I use your file I get an error like:

E: Unable to locate package ttf-mscorefonts-installer

I guess debian based and ubuntu based are different from each other.

Comment: Is your image debian-based or ubuntu based?

Comment: My image is Ubuntu based.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me with my Debian-based Docker image

```
RUN apt-get -q update \
    && apt-get -q install -y cabextract libmspack0 \
    && wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb \
    && dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```